# Django 1.6.1 Fixtures not getting loaded for Unittest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-fixtures, django-unittest

Django is not loading fixtures for the following test.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class DevViewsTests(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['device/fixtures/test_device.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.username = 'cws'
        self.email = 'alain.sturzenegger@gmail.com'
        self.password = 'cws123'
        self.test_user = User.objects.create_user(self.username, self.email, self.password)
        login = self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        self.assertEqual(login, True)

    def test_device_list(self):

        url = reverse('device-overview')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        logger.debug('GET[%s]:[%s]', url, response.status_code)

        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['device_list'], ['<device: Device Test 1>'])
```

This directs  to the following view But from that view I am not able to retrieve device_list

```
def overview(request):
    device_list = device.objects.all()
    print "List of devices"
    print device_list # getting blank list []
    context = {'device_list': device_list}
    return render(request, 'device/index.html', context)
```

My test_device.json file is as follows

```
[
{
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "device.device", 
    "fields": {
        "owner": 1, 
        "phone": "+41765687755", 
        "name": "Device Test 1", 
        "access_code": "1234"
    }
}
]
```

File Structure is

```
cws
--device
--fixtures
----test_device.json
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong? Please provide suggestion..

Comment: What happend if you specify `fixtures = ['test_device.json']` ?

Comment: Thank you so much , It worked. I was not setting FIXTURE_DIRS variable in settings.py file , so that I was taking relative path , How does it got the path then?

Comment: @falsetru : Do you know the reason why  fixtures = ['device/fixtures/test_device.json'] wont work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [fixture loading documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading):

> Once you’ve created a fixture and placed it **in a fixtures directory in
>   one of your INSTALLED_APPS**, you can use it in your unit tests by
>   specifying a fixtures class attribute on your django.test.TestCase
>   subclass:
>
> ...

Just specify the filename, not relative path from project directory:

```
fixtures = ['test_device.json']
```